# MySQL transactions: reads while writing

Tags: mysql, transactions, locking

I'm implementing PayPal Payments Standard in the website I'm working on. The question is not related to PayPal, I just want to present this question through my real problem.

PayPal can notify your server about a payment in two ways:

1. PayPal IPN - after each payment PayPal sends a (server-to-server) notification to a url (choose by you) with the transaction details.
2. PayPal PDT - after a payment (if you set this up in your PP account) PayPal will redirect the user back to your site, passing the transaction id in the url, so you can query PayPal about that transaction, to get details.

The problem is, that you can't be sure which one happens first:

- Will your server notified by IPN
- Will be the user redirected back to your site

Whichever is happening first, I want to be sure I'm not processing a transaction twice.
So, in both cases, I query my DB against the transaction id coming from paypal (and the payment status actually..but it doesn't matter now) to see if I already saved and processed that transaction. If not, I process it, and save the transaction id with other transaction details into my database.

**QUESTION**

What happens if I start processing the first request (let it be the PDT..so the user was redirected back to my site, but my server wasn't notified by IPN yet), but before I actually save the transaction to database, the second (the IPN) request arrives and it will try to process the transaction too, because it doesn't find it in DB.

I would love to make sure that while I'm writing a transaction into database, no other queries can read the table, looking for that given transaction id.

I'm using InnoDB, and don't want to lock the whole table, for the time of the write.
Can this be solved simply by transactions, have I to lock "manually" that row? I'm really confused, and I hope some more experienced mysql developers can help making this clear for me and solving the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Native database locks are almost useless in a Web context, particularly in situations like this. MySQL connections are generally NOT done in a persistent way - when a script shuts down, so does the MySQL connection and all locks are released and any in-flight transactions are rolled back.

e.g.

situation 1: You direct a user to paypal's site to complete the purchase

When they head off paypal, the script which sent over the http redirect will terminate and shuts down. Locks/transactions are released/rolled back, and they come back to a "virgin" status as far as the DB is concerned. Their record is no longer locked.

situation 2: Paypal does a server-to-server response. This will be done via a completely separate HTTP connection, utterly distinct from the connection established by the user to your server. That means any locks you establish in the yourserver<->user connection will be distinct from the paypal<->yourserver session, and the paypal response will encounter locked tables. And of course, there's no way of predicting when the paypal response comes in. If the network gods smile upon you and paypal's not swamped, you get a response very quickly and possibly while the user<->you connection is still open. If things are slow and the response is delayed, that response *MAY* encounter unlocked tables/rows because the user<->server session has completed.

You **COULD** use persistent MySQL connections, but they open up a whole other world of pain. e.g. consider the case where your script has a bug which gets triggered halfway through processing. You connection, do some transaction work, set up some locks... and then the script dies. Because the MySQL connection is persistent, MySQL will NOT see that the client script has died, and it will keep the transactions/locks in-flight. But the connection is still sitting there, in the shared pool waiting for another session to pick it up. When it invariably is, that new script has no idea that it's gotten this old "stale" connection. It'll step into the middle of a mess of locks and transactions it has no idea exists. You can VERY easily get yourself into a deadlock situation like this, because your buggy scripts have dumped garbage all over the system and other scripts cannot cope with that garbage.

Basically, unless you implement your own locking mechanism on top of the system, e.g. `UPDATE users SET locked=1 WHERE id=XXX`, you cannot use native DB locking mechanisms in a Web context except in 1-shot-per-script contexts. Locks should never be attempted over multiple independent requests.